# Get FrameBufferObject from vtkRenderWindow

Tags: c++, vtk, point-cloud-library, fbo

I'm pretty new to **VTK** world. I'm using **PCL Library** to visualize PointCloud data. The **PCLVisualizer** uses **VTK** library under the hood, to visualize the point clouds. I would like to access the FrameBuffer Object.

PCLVisualizer exposes **getRenderWindow()** method - that is **vtkRenderWindow**. Is it possible to get the framebuffer object (FBO) from the vtkRenderWindow class ?

Thanks